Setting up Sidebase/nuxt-auth to work when deployed to nuxt hub with nuxt application?
I am having a terrible time getting @sidebase/nuxt-auth working in nuxt hub.
My nuxt config:
import vuetify, { transformAssetUrls } from 'vite-plugin-vuetify';

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  compatibilityDate: '2024-11-01',
  components: [
    {
        path: '~/components',
        pathPrefix: false,
    },
  ],

  nitro: {
    experimental: {
        openAPI: true
    }
  },

  devtools: { enabled: true },

  build: {
    transpile: ['vuetify'],
  },

  vite: {
    vue: {
        template: {
            transformAssetUrls,
        },
    },
  },

  auth: {
    globalAppMiddleware: false,
    isEnabled: true,
    originEnvKey: 'AUTH_ORIGIN',
    baseURL: `${process.env.AUTH_ORIGIN}/api/auth`,
    provider: {
        type: 'authjs',
        defaultProvider: 'azure-ad',
        addDefaultCallbackUrl: true,
    },
  },

  runtimeConfig: {
    authSecret: 'my generated secret',
    authOrigin: process.env.AUTH_ORIGIN,
  },

  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss',
    (options, nuxt) => {
        nuxt.hooks.hook('vite:extendConfig', (config) => {
            // @ts-expect-error
            config.plugins.push(vuetify({ autoImport: true }))
        })
    },
    '@sidebase/nuxt-auth',
    '@nuxthub/core',
  ],
})

Then my server/api/auth/[...].ts
import { NuxtAuthHandler } from '#auth';
import AzureAD from 'next-auth/providers/azure-ad';

export default NuxtAuthHandler({
  secret: useRuntimeConfig().authSecret,
  providers: [
    // @ts-ignore
    AzureAD.default({
        clientId: 'my client id',
        clientSecret: 'my client secret',
        tenantId: 'my tenant id',
    }),
  ],
});

This works perfectly fine locally. I am able to load my page, trigger login flow, log in with my azure account, and get my info on my page. Once I deployed to nuxt hub, all I get are GET api/auth/session [500],Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'substring') errors and the page won't even load.
It is hitting https://my-nuxt-hub-alias-url.nuxt.dev/api/auth/session, which is where that should be. I see it in the API in the nuxt hub portal, but all it does is returns 500s and unsure how to even debug inside of sidebase...
I am wondering if anyone has used sidebase and deployed to nuxt hub successfully? My current auth set up is incredibly basic, but can't find any posts or information about combining these two (nuxt hub and sidebase).
I added my nuxt hub url to my callbacks in my azure application. That is working fine for localhost, so that should be set up correctly I'd think. I have allowed redirect urls set to:
http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/azure-ad
https://my-nuxt-hub-alias-url.nuxt.dev/api/auth/callback/azure-ad


Can you provide your GitHub repository?

It is private, so cannot. But this is an almost bare-bones nuxt app with sidebase added just to try to find a workable authentication library.
